# List of running notebooks on current Jupyter server in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I have been accessing a remote Jupyter server through my browser but for better debugging, I am now switching to accessing my server over SSH in Visual Studio Code. I installed the Jupyer extension and can run my notebooks fine. But in the browser interface, there is a "Running" tab (as shown in the image) that lists all the notebooks I am running and I can shut them down from there easily. How to do the same in VS Code? I just need to view this list. A terminal command, or anything that can tell me which notebooks are running will be very helpful.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be an visual studio issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71257239/5141404

I work in an alternative way, all files in the open editors is running jupyter notebook.

[image]