# List all running servers/notebooks

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter

Essentially, the question is in the title: how can I get a list of all running servers/notebooks, started from VSCode? I know about functions to do so for JupyterLab, but they don't work.

I've been able to locate `connection_file` of a notebook at `/tmp/tmp-*.json` that can be used to get `kernel_id` of a notebook, which in turn can be used to get the `PID` of that notebook (for example, by scanning the `/proc/PID`), but how can I get the name of that notebook?

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is not a way to get all the running notebooks / servers from within VS Code. That would be a good enhancement request to log on github though if you were interested:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues